# View and revoke Facebook access tokens

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth

This is more of a Facebook UI question than anything.
Sometimes I use Facebook to log into another site through oauth. How can I see which sites have used my Facebook for oauth login?

And follow-up, is there a way to revoke or reset the access tokens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=applications

That´s where all the App Logins are, and you can remove each App.